# CSS - Image disappeared when remove height

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make the following image responsive? When I try to remove height & width, the image just disappeared.

I am creating an image-map using CSS as I don't want to use an HTML MAP.

I want to create a responsive image.

```html
<div class="img-responsive" style="position:relative; height:1122px; width:779px; background:url(https://image.ibb.co/eZWkb7/0001.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;">
  <a style="background-color:red;position:absolute; top:319px; left:198px; width:61px; height:56px;" title="" alt="" href="1" target="_self"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking to make bg image cover your entire screen(for any device) and then place your anchor tags over that? Just to be clear, as you are not happy with the usual resolutions provided by the other users.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make width : 100%, without giving height properties.
That should make your element responsive.

TIPS : you should consider placing your style into a separate CSS file.

Comment: <div class="img-responsive" style="position:relative; width:100%; background:url(https://image.ibb.co/eZWkb7/0001.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;">

  <a style="background-color:red;position:absolute; top:319px; left:198px; width:61px; height:56px;" title="" alt="" href="1" target="_self"></a>
</div>

tried this but image still disappeared ...just white

Comment: Then it have to come from your CSS. Something is probably interfering. Happened to me and had to check my CSS until it works.
Plus, I see you are using a bootstrap class, so the width property should not even be useful. And avoid using background to place an image in your code. you should put a div and place your image in it, from your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Responsive images will automatically adjust to fit the size of the screen.

If you want to create responsive images which will automatically fit with your theme size, then you should add CSS class (.responsive) as below.

```
.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

After adding CSS class, you need to use responsive class in HTML as below.

```
<img src="nature.jpg" alt="Nature" class="responsive">
```